# Github account disabled for posting GIST's

Tags: api, github, github-api, gist

I created a github account because I wanted to use the GIST api as a make shift diff tool to compare 2 yaml files. It was working like a charm but my github account has now been flagged. Is this a breach of any rules ?? Its working like a charm and I would be sad to have to abandon it.

Got the following message on my account

`Your account has been flagged.
Because of that, your profile is hidden from the public. If you believe this is a mistake, contact support to have your account status reviewed.`

Comment: http://a-habakiri.hateblo.jp/entry/20161208accountflagged

Comment: that doesn't answer my question ? That was a personal account getting flagged, this is a bot account ? I would down vote your down vote :)

Comment: If you believe this is a mistake, contact support to have your account status reviewed.

Comment: # That's the same to me! Anybody can fixed it?

Comment: @xgqfrms I ended up emailing in and they re-enabled my account. have not had any trouble since then

Comment: @Donovan Thomson Thanks for your advice, it's OK now!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer for this is an un-easy one. I emailed in and got the same automated response and the account was re-activated. Have not had any problems since then so hopefully it is not a breach of their terms of use

Comment: I'm not sure the response is automated. Or if it is, it's terribly slow to respond.